# Jquery isn't setting radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to have "set all" radio buttons at the bottom of my popup control so when the user has a long list of conflicts to resolve, they can just select one of the radio buttons and the option will be quickly select. However, my javascript fires, and seems to find the radio button, but fails to actually set the radio button.

I have a gridview gvErrors that is being looped though and in the second cell of each gridview row is a table with the options (tblOptions). I have tried using `.attr("checked", true)`, `.setAttribute("checked", true)`, and `.prop("checked", true)`. I am receiving no errors, in the console, but the radio buttons all remain unchecked. Any help with this would be appreciated. Below is the Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function selectAll(option) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvErrors.ClientID%>");

        for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var row = grid.rows[i];
            var table =  $(row).find("tblOptions");
            var radio = $(table).find("input[name*=" + option + "]:radio");
            //$('td input:radiobutton', '#tblOptions').prop('checked', true);
            $(radio).prop("checked", "checked");
            var test = "";
        }
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //This handles the rows or colums selection          
        $("#<%=rdbCancelAll.ClientID%>").click(function() {
           selectAll("rdbCancel");
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //This handles the rows or colums selection          
        $("#<%=rdbReplaceAll.ClientID%>").click(function() {
           selectAll("rdbReplace");
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //This handles the rows or colums selection          
        $("#<%=rdbRenameAll.ClientID%>").click(function() {
           selectAll("rdbRename");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Small example of the gridview:

```
<table class="tableinfo nocollapse c6" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors">
<tbody>
  <tr class="tableinfobody tableinfoGray">
    <th scope="col"><span class="c1">Current Name</span></th>

    <th scope="col"><span class="c1">Options</span></th>

    <th scope="col">Differences</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tableinfobody">
    <td class="l"><span id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_lblName">Test1</span></td>

    <td class="l">
      <table id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_tblOptions" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbCancel" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$Options" value="rdbCancel" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbCancel">Cancel adding signal.</label></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbReplace" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$Options" value="rdbReplace" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbReplace">Replace curent signal with
            imported signal.</label></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbRename" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$Options" value="rdbRename" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_rdbRename">Rename imported signal to:</label>
            <input name="ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$txtNewName" type="text" value=
            "Test1_1" id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_txtNewName" class="c2" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td class="l">
      <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$hfParamInternalUnmatched"
      id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_hfParamInternalUnmatched" value=
      "EBC1-Test1" /> <input type="hidden" name=
      "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl02$hfParamInternalMatched" id=
      "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl02_hfParamInternalMatched" value="Test1" />

      <table class="tableinfo c5" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tableinfobody tableinfoGray">
            <th>Value Name</th>

            <th>Current</th>

            <th>Imported</th>
          </tr>

          <tr class="tableinfobody">
            <td class="c3">Unit</td>

            <td class="c4"></td>

            <td class="c4">flag</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tableinfobody tableinfoGray">
    <td class="l"><span id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_lblName">Test2</span></td>

    <td class="l">
      <table id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_tblOptions" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbCancel" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$Options" value="rdbCancel" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbCancel">Cancel adding signal.</label></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbReplace" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$Options" value="rdbReplace" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbReplace">Replace curent signal with
            imported signal.</label></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbRename" type="radio" name=
            "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$Options" value="rdbRename" /><label for=
            "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_rdbRename">Rename imported signal to:</label>
            <input name="ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$txtNewName" type="text" value=
            "Test2_1" id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_txtNewName" class="c2" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td class="l">
      <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$hfParamInternalUnmatched"
      id="ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_hfParamInternalUnmatched" value=
      "HCMData3-Testw" /> <input type="hidden" name=
      "ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$hfParamInternalMatched" id=
      "ctl00_Main_gvErrors_ctl03_hfParamInternalMatched" value=
      "PrimaryData3-Testw" />

      <table class="tableinfo c5" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tableinfobody tableinfoGray">
            <th>Value Name</th>

            <th>Current</th>

            <th>Imported</th>
          </tr>

          <tr class="tableinfobody">
            <td class="c3">SA</td>

            <td class="c4">3, 239</td>

            <td class="c4">239</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tableinfobody tableinfoBlue">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you have so many script tags and so many document.ready functions?

Comment: @Sushil It's the design format work wants. Every event wrapped in its own script/document ready.

Comment: @Trasiva it's unnecessary and bad practice to have it written that way

Comment: yeah @Trasiva. this is not the right way to code. anyways have you tried $(radio).checked = true?? instead of $(radio).prop("checked", "checked"); it should be something like $('input:radio[name=ctl00$Main$gvErrors$ctl03$Options]')[i].checked = true; but you can always select only 1 from a radiogroup

Comment: To be clear, do you mean to select all the radio buttons on the page, or just one from each group?

Comment: @rpl One from each group. If rdbCancelAll was selected, then rdbCancel in from each row will be selected.

Comment: Did you check if the code entered the loop at all?

Comment: @Sushil That's why I was trying to loop through the gridview and use the *= to try and avoid the ClientID mess ASP makes.

Comment: I am working on a fiddle for this. will try to replace the clientId

Comment: As I mentioned above @loli, yes, it loops through the code just fine, definitions are being set for each of my variables, although looking at it now, I am not 100% on if it's the element definition or not.

Comment: @Trasiva try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3u3z4bLn/1/ and let me know if it is clean and works for u.

Comment: your jsfiddle only works once

Comment: It works @Sushil, it does however stop responding after exactly four clicks interestingly enough.

Comment: @Trasiva let me check. i also forgot to remove the for loop in it. what do you mean by once @loli?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/3u3z4bLn/2/

Comment: Yea...that got it @loli. Allows for multiple changes without locking up, and cuts off almost a half dozen lines of code. I guess I was just over complicating things. I'll keep trying to push the office coding standards for javascript to be cleaner with few scripts too.

Comment: don't forget to remove my console.log and your // comment too, I used it for testing only :)

Comment: Yea, I did. The var = test bit was just a break point for the console, haha. If you want to actually whip up a quick answer I'll give you credit @loli.

Comment: well nice work @loli. you modified my fiddle and made it work. i guess i didn't test mine properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value as a selector like so

```
 function selectAll(option) {
            var radio = $("input[value=" + option + "]");
            $(radio).prop("checked", "checked");
        }

     $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
         var value = $(this).data('attr');
            selectAll(value);
         });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3z4bLn/3/